# MatLAB- defining variables more efficiently, with loops?

Tags: performance, matlab

I'm very sure my code is inefficient right now, I'm looking for guidance in making it more efficient by using loops to define variables.

For example

```
Y = imread('1Y.png')
Z = imread('1Z.png')

VariableAZAZ = cat(1,AZ,AZ)
VariableAZBZ = cat(1,AZ,BZ)
VariableAZCZ = cat(1,AZ,CZ)
```

And on a related note,

```
CombinedAZAZAZBZ = {VariableAZAZ, VariableAZBZ}
```

It's super tedious to not use some sort of loop but I'm a little bit lost on how to start.
Essentially my question is if there is a way to take advantage of the fact that the variable name is indicative of what values are part of the variable.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a bajillion files like this you want to load? Or is it just a couple?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest using a [Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) here:

```
Y = imread('1Y.png')
Z = imread('1Z.png')

% ... load/compute AZ, BZ, CZ, ...

my_map = containers.Map();

% save into the map

my_map('AZAZ') = cat(1,AZ,AZ);
my_map('AZBZ') = cat(1,AZ,BZ);
my_map('AZCZ') = cat(1,AZ,CZ);
% ...

% retrieve the data from the map

data = my_map('AZAZ');
```

A Map creates a 1:1 mapping from key -> value, so if you're using a pattern for the keys, then it should be pretty easy to write your code to compute the keys as you need them.

Now, you don't even need to store cell arrays of variables, if you're only
reading them:

```
% don't do this!
my_map('AZAZAZBZ') = {my_map('AZAZ'), my_map('AZBZ')};
```

Because you can just as easily read directly from `my_map` using keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to load things into cell arrays rather than having a crazy number of different variable names. Maybe something like:

```
my_images = cell(26,1);
for(i=1:26)  %iterate from 1A.png to 1Z.png
   filename = ['1', char('A'+i-1), '.png']
   my_images{i} = imread(filename);
end

combined_images = cell(26,26);
for(i=1:26)
  for(j=1:26)
    combined_images{i,j} = cat(1, my_images{i}, my_images{j});
  end
end
```

#### alternative way to load files

```
filenames = {'1A.png','1B.png','1C.png'}; %put all filenames in a cell array
n_files = length(filenames);
my_images = cell(n_files,1);
for(i=1:n_files)    %iterate over the different filenames loading each one
   my_images{i} = imread(filenames{i});
end
```